# Output ASP.NET model in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Actually I'm working on an old existing ASP.NET project.
My task is to add an first date of the week output to the calendar week output.

Example:

[image: Example]

The data comes from an ASP.NET model.

Actually it works like this:

```
function SetCalendarWeeks(data) {
    $("#calendarWeek1").text("KW "+data.Week1.Number);
    $("#calendarWeek2").text("KW "+data.Week2.Number);
    $("#calendarWeek3").text("KW "+data.Week3.Number);
    $("#calendarWeek4").text("KW "+data.Week4.Number);
    $("#calendarWeek5").text("KW "+data.Week5.Number);

    if (!data.MonthHas6Weeks) {
        $(".collapsable").hide();
        $(".dummyColumn").show();

        if (data.HideLastInputbox) { 
            $("#planned10").hide();
        } else {
            $("#planned10").show();
        }
    } else {
        $("#calendarWeek6").text("KW " + data.Week6.Number);
        $(".collapsable").show();
        $(".dummyColumn").hide();
        $("#planned10").show();

        if (data.HideLastInputbox) { 
            $("#planned12").hide();
        } else {
            $("#planned12").show();
        }
    }
```

What I tried is to add this:

```
document.getElementById("calendarWeek1").innerHTML = "KW "+data.Week1.Number+"&nbsp;<span class='firstDate'>"+data.Week1.FirstDate+"</span>";
```

But I got this:

[image: Example 2]

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is the type of `Week1.FirstDate`?

Comment: public DateTime FirstDate { get; set; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your date returned by your model to a JavaScript date.

Date returned by your model is in the following format:

```
/Date(1475272800000)/
```

I made a function to convert your date; if the parameter `short` is `true` the date is converted to the format `DD.MM.YYYY`:

```
function ConvertDate(d, short) {
    var regex = /-?\d+/;
    var match = regex.exec(d);
    var date = new Date(parseInt(match[0]))

    if (short) {
        date = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "." + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "." + date.getFullYear();
    }

    return date;
}
```

So you can use the function like this:

```
ConvertDate(data.Week1.FirstDate, true)
```

The full line:

```
document.getElementById("calendarWeek1").innerHTML = "KW "+data.Week1.Number+"&nbsp;<span class='firstDate'>"+ConvertDate(data.Week1.FirstDate, true)+"</span>";
```

Comment: After I add this, nothing changed by changing the month :(

but now Visual Studio got me this: "Property of global variable 'FirstDate' is possibly never assigned"

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ConvertToDate(){
var rawDate = $("#rawDate").val();
var myDate = new Date(Number(rawDate));
$("#myDate").val(myDate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
input: <input type="text" id="rawDate" value="1482706800000" /> <button onclick="ConvertToDate()">Convert</button>
<br /><br />
output: <input type="text" id="myDate" value="" readonly />
```

convert your data to date in javascript:

```
var myDate = new Date(data.Week1.FirstDate);
```